# Assign HDMI outputs of a stacked Raspberry Pi to separate outputs

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, home-automation

If you stacked 4 Raspberry Pi's, as you would a regular cluster computer, can the HDMIs of each Raspberry Pi be assigned to separate AV outputs or are there any programs, that do this for you. For example, say you have 2 TVs and both are connected to the Raspberry Pi cluster by 2 separate HDMI cables. They are connected to 2 different Raspberry Pi's in the cluster. Neither one is the controller Raspberry Pi. One person wants to watch CCTV and the other wants to listen to music on the media center. Using just the controller Raspberry Pi and Raspbian, can you send 2 different HDMI outputs to the 2 TVs. The outcome is shown in the diagram below:

[image: diagram]

Comment: So each RPi just sends video to its own device? How is that different from several RPi boards running independently?

Comment: Because with a Raspberry Pi cluster, you only interact with the controller, that uses the processors from all of the Raspberry Pi's. We want to use the HDMI ports too. By clustering the Raspberry Pi's, this will allow multiple video outputs, with better controll over the processing power, therefore making it much more versatile and efficient.